# Redirect Regular Expressions with.htaccess

Tags: regex, redirect

I have a little problem to make a redirection in .htaccess.

I creadet redirection by plugin on my Wordpress Site:

https://example.com/priv -> m.me

And it works well.

But if I share my link "https://example.com/priv" in social media, then the e.g. Facebook automatically adds to my link:

https://example.com/priv?fbclid=IwAR03gHqwIcjNTHDhltYhoF1mX-J4tw7x5YWqGGgwQQDmY1yiKqO_NJ5bsmA

Then I get error 404 and the redirection does not work.

I tried with .htaccess make the redirection:

```
#PRIV
RewriteRule ^PRIV?(.*)$ https://m.me/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^priv?(.*)$ https://m.me/ [R=301,L]
```

But there is problem that my link e.g /privacy-policy/ also is redirecting to https://m.me/

How can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:priv|PRIV)\?.*$ https://m.me/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work. Still I get the redirection of link: https://example.com/privacy-policy/ - I do not want.

Comment: @kibus90 oh sry I didnt see the note that you have a privacy-policy link, I updated my answer, please check it now

Comment: Hi,

The following link gives Error 404.


https://example.com/priv?fbclid=IwAR3fY54gLlGdPmH2x_YAKpoNUHTwfmNUT1B30r_Sjk8wgH0CrPviToLHI14

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I fount solution:

`#PRIV
RewriteRule ^(PRIV|PRIV\/|priv|priv\/)$ https://m.me/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(priv|PRIV)\?.*$ https://m.me/ [R=301,L]`

This does not redirec the links with:

```
example.com/priva
example.com/prive
example.com/privacy-policy
```

but it will be works for:

```
`xmaple.com/priv
example.com/priv/
example.com/PRIV/
example.com/PRIV
example.com/PRIV?fbclid=transfer
```

etc.